# Can't see dropout in Tensorboard graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am applying dropout to the first layer in the following way :

```
out = layers.fully_connected(X, num_outputs=hidden[0], activation_fn=None)
out1 = tf.nn.relu(out)
drop_out = tf.nn.dropout(out1, keep_prob) #keep_prob = 0.5

out2 = layers.fully_connected(drop_out, num_outputs=hidden[1], activation_fn=None)
out2 = tf.nn.relu(out2)

out3 = layers.fully_connected(out4, num_outputs=num_actions, activation_fn=None)
```

But I cannot see dropout in tensorboard computational graph. Do I need to explicitly write a command in the summary to include Dropout layer ?

[Tensorboard graph for the above model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBwPf.png)